# How to specify build configuration when using local git to publish to Azure

Tags: azure

I would like to use [local git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-local-git?tabs=cli) to publish a project to Azure.

I need to specify the `*.csproj` (there are multiple projects in my solution) and build configuration (debug/release/etc.).

I only see how to specify the project [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#using-app-settings-instead-of-a-deployment-file).

How can I also specify the build configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the parameter `SCM_BUILD_ARGS`. [Here is the documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings).

e.g. via a `.deployment` file:

```
[config]
SCM_BUILD_ARGS=-p:configuration=myconfig
PROJECT=WebApi.csproj
```

Which will result in a build log like this:

```
remote:   Copying file from "C:\home\site\repository\obj\myconfig\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\WebAPI.dll" to "C:\local\Temp\8d93f0d60e8e884\WebAPI.dll".
remote:   Copying file from "C:\home\site\repository\obj\myconfig\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\WebAPI.exe" to "C:\local\Temp\8d93f0d60e8e884\WebAPI.exe".
remote:   Copying file from "C:\home\site\repository\obj\myconfig\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\WebAPI.pdb" to "C:\local\Temp\8d93f0d60e8e884\WebAPI.pdb".
remote:   Copying file from "C:\home\site\repository\obj\myconfig\net5.0\PubTmp\Out\WebAPI.runtimeconfig.json" to "C:\local\Temp\8d93f0d60e8e884\WebAPI.runtimeconfig.json".
```

Comment: Thanks. I’ll try this later. Can you post where you found the documentation for this?

Comment: The link to the documentation is in the first line of the answer. I found it pretty much by accident. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings